# looping through loops in python?

Tags: python, iteration

I'm trying to solve this problem on the easy section of coderbyte and the prompt is:

Have the function ArrayAdditionI(arr) take the array of numbers stored in arr and return the string true if any combination of numbers in the array can be added up to equal the largest number in the array, otherwise return the string false. For example: if arr contains [4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3] the output should return true because 4 + 6 + 10 + 3 = 23. The array will not be empty, will not contain all the same elements, and may contain negative numbers.

Here's my solution.

```
def ArrayAddition(arr):
arr = sorted(arr, reverse=True)
large = arr.pop(0)
storage = 0
placeholder = 0
for r in range(len(arr)):
    for n in arr:
        if n + storage == large: return True
        elif n + storage < large: storage += n
        else: continue
    storage = 0
    if placeholder == 0: placeholder = arr.pop(0)
    else: arr.append(placeholder); placeholder = arr.pop(0)
return False
```

print ArrayAddition([2,95,96,97,98,99,100])

I'm not even sure if this is correct, but it seems to cover all the numbers I plug in. I'm wondering if there is a better way to solve this through algorithm which I know nothing of. I'm thinking a for within a for within a for, etc loop would do the trick, but I don't know how to do that.

What I have in mind is accomplishing this with A+B, A+C, A+D ... A+B+C  ... A+B+C+D+E

e.g)

```
for i in range(len(arr):
print "III: III{}III".format(i)
storage = []
for j in range(len(arr):
    print "JJ: II({}),JJ({})".format(i,j)

    for k in range(len(arr):
        print "K: I{}, J{}, K{}".format(i,j,k)
```

I've searched all over and found the suggestion of itertool, but I'm wondering if there is a way to write this code up more raw.

Thanks.

Comment: Google for subset sum, that should get you started.

Comment: As a side note, what you're calling arrays aren't arrays. They're lists (ArrayLists to be precise, but lists nonetheless). In Python, "arrays" usually refers to NumPy arrays, which are a different data structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A recursive solution:

```
def GetSum(n, arr):
    if len(arr) == 0 and n != 0:
        return False
    return (n == 0 or  
      GetSum(n, arr[1:]) or  
      GetSum(n-arr[0], arr[1:]))

def ArrayAddition(arr):
    arrs = sorted(arr)
    return GetSum(arrs[-1], arrs[:-1])

print ArrayAddition([2,95,96,97,98,99,100])
```

The GetSum function returns False when the required sum is non-zero and there are no items in the array. Then it checks for 3 cases:

1. If the required sum, n, is zero then the goal is achieved.
2. If we can get the sum with the remaining items after the first item is removed, then the goal is achieved.
3. If we can get the required sum minus the first element of the list on the rest of the list the goal is achieved.

Comment: I don't know much about recursions, but this is something I'll have to start trying to learn, THanks!

Comment: Adding an explanation would probably be really good for the OP.  Also, you should probably use `.sort()` instead of `.sorted()`.  Nice solution, though.

Comment: I'm confused as to why when it loops into the if statement, the function just doesn't stop and return false. Instead it keeps looping. (eg. when n = 100 and arr = []

Answer (score 2):

Your solution doesn't work.

```
>>> ArrayAddition([10, 11, 20, 21, 30, 31, 60])
False
```

The simple solution is to use `itertools` to iterate over all subsets of the input (that don't contain the largest number):

```
def subsetsum(l):
    l = list(l)
    target = max(l)
    l.remove(l)
    for subset_size in xrange(1+len(l)):
        for subset in itertools.combinations(l, subset_size):
            if sum(subset) == target:
                return True
    return False
```

If you want to avoid itertools, you'll need to generate subsets directly. That can be accomplished by counting in binary and using the set bits to determine which elements to pick:

```
def subsetsum(l):
    l = list(l)
    target = max(l)
    l.remove(l)
    for subset_index in xrange(2**len(l)):
        subtotal = 0
        for i, num in enumerate(l):
            # If bit i is set in subset_index
            if subset_index & (1 << i):
                subtotal += num
        if subtotal == target:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Huh? What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I forgot that you want to check all possible combinations. Use this instead:

```
def ArrayAddition(l):
    for length in range(2, len(l)):
        for lst in itertools.combinations(l, length):
            if sum(lst) in l:
                print(lst, sum(lst))
                return True
    return False
```

One-liner solution:

```
>>> any(any(sum(lst) in l for lst in itertools.combinations(l, length)) for length in range(2, len(l)))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Generate all the sums of the powerset and test them against the max

```
def ArrayAddition(L):
    return any(sum(k for j,k in enumerate(L) if 1<<j&i)==max(L) for i in range(1<<len(L)))
```

You could improve this by doing some preprocessing - find the max first and remove it from L

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do it...

**Code:**

```
import itertools
def func(l):
    m = max(l)
    rem = [itertools.combinations([x for x in l if not x == m],i) for i in range(2,len(l)-1)]
    print [item for i in rem for item in i if sum(item)==m ]


if __name__=='__main__':
    func([1,2,3,4,5])
```

**Output:**

```
[(1, 4), (2, 3)]
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, simply this should return what you want:

```
2*max(a)<=sum(a)
```

Comment: Sorry, I believe you havnt understood the question correctly :)

Comment: Hmm, that's what I suspected :)